# ReadOnlyProperty - type arguments automatically inferred not validating bounds

Tags: kotlin, syntax

I'm trying to inject value into class property using **by** keyword.
No problem implementing the code below.

```
open class Component
class ComponentA: Component()

class Equipment(val components: List<Component>) {

    inline fun <reified T> getComponent(): T? {
        return components.firstOrNull { it is T } as T?
    }

    val ca: ComponentA by find<ComponentA>()  //this is what I intend to do
    val ca1: List<ComponentA> by find()       //no error or warning
    val ca2 by find<List<ComponentA>>()       //Error: Type argument is not within its bounds
}

inline fun <reified T> find(): ReadOnlyProperty<Equipment, T> where T : Component {
    return ReadOnlyProperty { ref, _ -> ref.getComponent<T>() ?: throw Exception("Not found") }
}
```

But I find it is weird that the `val ca1: List<ComponentA> by find()` not showing any error or warning. Error still show normally when I try `val ca2 by find<List<ComponentA>>()`.

Can anybody explain why this happened and how to make sure **ca1** definition syntax is invalid.

I'm using:

- AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.7.10 hotspot
- Kotlin 1.6.21
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2

Comment: This seems like a compiler bug to me. If I remove ca2 so it compiles and then try to access ca1, a ClassCastException is thrown. Also getComponent can never return a Component as components contains Equipment and not Components

Comment: Can you explain why you think `val ca1: List<ComponentA> by find()` shouldn't compile?

Comment: The find() method require type variable T which must be extend of class Component `where T : Component`. If change the code to `val ca1: Equipment by find()` it will not compile so why it does when it's a List

Answer (score 0):

well I think the problem is from IDEA with the compiler, I tried using android functions like `viewModels()` with List instead of ViewModel and I had the same problem, the IDEA will not show any error:

[image]

but when you compile the code you will get an error:

[image]

so you can ignore this, it's just a problem with the IDEA, also you have some mistakes in your code,

`val components: List<Equipment>` this should be `val components: List< Component >`

`return components.firstOrNull { it is T } as T` and this should be `return components.firstOrNull { it is T } as T?` because you cannot cast a null type to a non-null type

so your code should look like this:

```
open class Component
class ComponentA: Component()

class Equipment(val components: List<Component>) {

    inline fun <reified T> getComponent(): T? {
        return components.firstOrNull { it is T } as T?
    }

    val ca: ComponentA by find<ComponentA>()  //this is what I intend to do
    // val ca1: List<ComponentA> by find()       //no error or warning
    // val ca2 by find<List<ComponentA>>()       //Error: Type argument is not within its bounds
}

inline fun <reified T> find(): ReadOnlyProperty<Equipment, T> where T : Component {
    return ReadOnlyProperty { ref, _ -> ref.getComponent<T>() ?: throw Exception("Not found") }
}
```

Comment: Yeah there are some bug in the code. I just create a simple version of the actual code which I not allow to share

Comment: @LươngTiếnĐồng as I said for the error is just a problem with the IDEA, I'm using android studio which is built on IntelliJ IDEA and I'm having the same problem even with android built in functions.